# How to fix "error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image"

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I was looking at someone else's code and following python code;

```
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path to the input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

gives the following error on the last line;

```
usage: sample.py [-h] -i IMAGE
sample.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image
```

How can I fix this problem? Nothing I have tried so far seems to help.

Comment: Did you try providing the argument it asked for?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. You mean the input placeholder is causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running `sample.py`, you need to specify the `-i`/`--image` argument:

```
python sample.py --image image/cat.png
```

If you want the `image` argument to be optional, remove `required=True`:

```
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", help="path to the input image")
```

Comment: I didn't know you could/should do that. Thanks.