# Resolve error in Python3, The following arguments are required: -d/--dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, scikit-learn

I am getting this error trying to run a program in python3 in MacOS. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thank you already! It would be great help.
This project is to detect Parkison's Disease using computer vision.
My python3 version is 3.8

```
usage: detect_parkinsons.py [-h] -d DATASET [-t TRIALS]
detect_parkinsons.py: error: the following arguments are required: -d/--dataset
```

This is the code:

```
# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
    help="path to input dataset")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--trials", type=int, default=5,
    help="# of trials to run")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

Comment: You have not shown what command you are using to run the script, but it seems likely that you are not giving it the `-d` (or `--dataset`) option that it needs, despite making this a required option.

Comment: I just simply go to the shell and run it

Comment: But please edit the question to show exactly what you type in order to run it.

Comment: You can't *just run it*... Your program has a **required** argument `-d` that must be passed, so you need to run it as for example: `python3 main.py -d mydata`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55531306/how-to-fix-error-the-following-arguments-are-required-i-image)

Answer (score 0):

i think path of dataset you missed so please add dataset path then it will work fine.

```
detect_parkinsons.py -d [Enter path of dataset]
```